# Bootstrap : Is it possible to add forms on carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap4.
I've been developing a soccer website which allow users to add custom players. For that I thought Carousel was a nice thing because the user can press the arrows to navigate through forms and add as many players as they want.
Can we make it just by using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I will give you an example of a form that runs on the first slide. The rest of the slides/customization is up to your imagination. Don't think about my example too much. I threw it together to show it's possible.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <form class="form-horizontal" style="width:50%;">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Form Name</legend> <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control input-md" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div><!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordinput">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control input-md" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item"><img alt="Second slide" class="d-block img-fluid" src="..."></div>
    <div class="carousel-item"><img alt="Third slide" class="d-block img-fluid" src="..."></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks RDumais. I will mark your answer as the correct but i will not use it because i realized it would be better if i use some javascript to add forms.